# how mock a logger service in jasmine which is initiated inside angular 2 component constructor

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have created a logger custom NPM package and which i am using in my components as written below . I am unable to mock that service in my test case using normal provide and useClass method. when I use that method I am getting an error "Failed: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" , which may be because I am using http service inside logger npm package .

```
// component code.. 


export class AppComponent {

import { LoggerService } from 'logger';

 private loggerService: LoggerService;

 constructor() {
        this.loggerService = LoggerService.CreateLogger('my-app.component');
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loggerService.traceStarted('ngOnInit');
          //my other codes
        this.loggerService.traceCompleted('ngOnInit');
    }
}


// test case code.. 

import { LoggerService } from 'logger';
describe('my app Component', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   { provide: LoggerService , useClass: MockLoggerService  },

  })

}));


it('should create the app component', async(() => {

    TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent );
        const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
        expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    });


  }));
```

Comment: Please include definition of `MockLoggerService` - this may have to do with how this mock class is created.

Comment: hi, dmcgrandle this is the mock service code export class MockLoggerService {

    CreateLogger () {
        return new MockLoggerService ()
    }

    traceStarted() {

    }

    traceCompleted() {

    }

    info (){

    }
}

Comment: inside the logger service i am using service logger // this.logOptions = ServiceLocator.injector.get('logOptions');

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: **don't call new yourself** outside of Angulars DI.

If you want an instance per component (I don't like it) provide it at the component level.

```
import { Component, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import { LoggerService } from './logger.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: LoggerService,
      useFactory: () => new LoggerService('app-component'),
    }
  ]

})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private loggerService: LoggerService) {
    this.loggerService.info("hello")
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pw9pyf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the replay . Problem is my logger service is a non angular service, it is just a class. only a npm package.  So i am unable to use the system you are provided. I am getting this error  "Constructor of class 'LoggerService' is private and only accessible within the class declaration."

Comment: inside the logger service i am using serviclocator this.logOptions = ServiceLocator.injector.get('logOptions');  in the test ii am getting this error " Failed: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined "

Comment: As long as your LoggerService has no dependencies to sth provided through  Angular it shouldn't  be a problem to provide a class that is lacking the `@Injectable` annotation since this is only required if you want to use Angulars DI inside of the LoggerService. But please, if it doesnt work provide more code, way more code.